# HAProxy Proxing non-real path

Tags: networking, reverse-proxy, haproxy

Using HAProxy I'm trying to proxy a site where the URL doesn't match the path of the proxied destination server. Right now I'm able to use `reqrep` to edit the path and at my browser I end up fetching the index.html however it doesn't load any of it's support files (.css, .js ext) even though they are listed by reference.

For example www.mysite.com/maps --haproxy--> www.backend-server.com. In my config I remove /maps so we end up at the web-server root of www.backend-server.com and are able to fetch index.html but now when the .css & .js try to load they can't as they are referencing `www.mysite.com/icons/text.gif` when I'm guessing they should be referencing `www.mysite.com/maps/icons/text.gif`. Also I can't just make a rule saying .css & .js goto somebackend because I have different app's which all have this problem and pull their .js & .css files from different places. How do I do this the right way? Here's my config:

```
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000


frontend dev
    bind xxx.xx.x.30:80
    option forwardfor except 127.0.0.0/8

    #Routing based on Web App
    acl filebrowser url_beg /maps
    use_backend dev.maps if maps

backend dev.maps
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)maps[/]?(.*)     \1\2
        server maps maps.backend-server.com:80 check
```

Comment: I don't see your `reqrep` statements.. Can you post the full config?

Comment: Sorry bad copy paste added.

Comment: Are the locations wrong in the HTML being returned from the backends, or is HAProxy just not dealing with them properly?

Comment: so after checking the returned .css & .js type files are absolute paths, like /css/mycss.css. I'm guessing as long as its like that there is nothing the proxy can do to direct those files to the correct place, right?

Comment: Indeed, it can only manipulate headers and such. Nothing to do with the body. I know there's an Nginx [module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) that can do that though.